# Changing the background color of a JFrame icon on the windows taskbar

Tags: java, background, icons, jframe, taskbar

I have a JFrame application within which I have invoked setIconImage() which changes the icon image (teapot image) which displays on the windows bar.

How do I change the background color, that appears when you hover over the image on the windows bar? Currently the background color that is displayed is light blue.

I am positive that it can be done, as your typical big programs have colors which tie in with their design, eclipse for instance uses purple.

Comment: Don't use transparent pixels in your Icon.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the background color of the taskbar icon. The color is determined by windows from the dominant color of your icon. If you want another background color then you will have to change your icon.

This feature in windows 7 is called [Color Hot-track](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/e7/archive/2008/11/20/happy-anniversary-windows-on-the-evolution-of-the-taskbar.aspx).

Comment: that's weird, my gif icon image doesn't have any light blue in it, its all shades of grey. Anyway, thanks for the info, I'll try playing around with the icon image then. Thanks.